# Count multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have my main array:

```
array(6) { 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(15) "Extension" 
        [1]=> int(1) 
        [2]=> string(6) "3,00 " 
    } 
    [2]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(32) "Physics " 
        [1]=> string(1) "1" 
        [2]=> string(6) "3,00 " 
    } 
    [3]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(31) "Physics " 
        [1]=> int(1) 
        [2]=> string(6) "6,00 " 
    } 
    [4]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(34) "Desk" 
        [1]=> int(4) 
        [2]=> string(8) "127,00 " 
    } 
    [5]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(18) "assistance" 
        [1]=> int(1) 
        [2]=> string(7) "12,50 " 
    } 
    [6]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(15) "Extension" 
        [1]=> int(1) 
        [2]=> string(6) "3,00 " 
    } 
}
```

My expected output is:

```
   Extension 2 
   Physics 2
   Desk 1 
   Assistance 1
```

The result must be in an resultarray
How can I do? I tried with array_count_values function but don't work.

How can I stock answear: 
I tried this code but It doesn't work

```
  $tabrecap = array();
  foreach($counts as $key=>$value){
   //echo $key." qte".$value;
  $tabrecap = array ($key,$value,$valueOption);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count_values.asp may be help you

Comment: @Lovemyfate I already tried this function , but it's multidimensionnal array so It doesn't work :(

Comment: you can use foreach and count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked in comment,Please try this:-

```
<?php
$array =   array( '1'=> array('0'=>"Extension", '1'=> 1, '2'=>"3,00 " ), '2'=> array('0'=>"Physics",'1'=>"1","3,00 " ),'3'=> array('0'=>"Physics",'1'=>1,"6,00 "),'4'=> array('0'=>"Desk",'1'=>4,"127,00 "),'5'=> array('0'=>"assistance",'1'=>1,"12,50 " ),'6'=> array('0'=>"Extension",'1'=>1,"3,00 "));

$count = array();

$i = 0;

foreach ($array as $key=>$arr) {
  // Add to the current group count if it exists
  if (isset($count[$i][$arr[0]])) {
    $count[$i][$arr[0]]++;
  }
  else $count[$i][$arr[0]] = 1;

  $i++;
}
print_r($count);
 ?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/379176

Comment: Is it possible to create an array like this : array [0] =>{ [0]=> Extension [1]=>2 } { [0] =>Physics [1] => 2 }....

Comment: [Check This](https://eval.in/379147) I think this is not what OP has asked in question

Comment: @Uchiha thanks for pointing out. but i think it's easy to track that.but also i edited my answer to get rid of that. thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Looping is the answer.

```
<?php
// untested

$counts = Array();
foreach( $array as $subArray ){
    $value = $subArray[0];
    $counts[ $value ] = ( isset($counts[ $value ]) )
        ? $counts[ $value ] + 1
        : 1;
}

var_dump( $counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a loop and use first item of each array as key :

```
$array = array(
    array("Extension", 1, "3,00"),
    array("Physics", "1", "3,00"),
    array("Physics", 1, "6,00 ")
);
$count = array();

foreach($array as $a)
    $count[$a[0]]++;

var_dump($count); // array(2) { ["Extension"]=> int(1) ["Physics"]=> int(2) }
```

Comment: thanks , It s what I want , I tried a foreach but I was wrong in index

Comment: Your code will generate a notice for each not defined index in `$count`

Comment: ya , It's generate this notice , so It's wrong , I am sorry